# How do I auto-check a box with in a Access form when a particular option is chosen from the preceding "source" box

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in Access that I need to automate a little.. When the "source" is selected as "call" I want to trigger the "OT" box to be selected (with a checkmark).. IF the "source" box is selected as any other option I do not want the "OT" box to check... What's the best way to set this up?

Comment: The best way to do this is use VBA code for the AfterUpdate event of your "source" box/list/option group that checks or unchecks the OT box according to the selected "source" value.

Comment: Don't even need OT yes/no field. Source field has the necessary info, checkbox is just a visual representation of the data. This can be calculated when needed. Expression in checkbox ControlSource: `=[source]="call"`.